# Check type of constant without widening type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to typecheck the value assigned to a variable without widening the type?

For example,

```
const a = {foo: "hi"} as const; // typeof = {foo: "hi"}

type THasFoo = {foo: string};
const b: THasFoo = {foo: "hi"} as const; // typeof = THasFoo
```

I'd like to check that whatever I assigned to `a` has member `foo`, but without losing the type information of what that value was.

---

Note: specifically I'm interested in the kind of checking that comes from direct assignment. E.g.

```
const a = {foo: "hi", bar: "world"} as const;

type THasFoo = {foo: string};
const b: THasFoo = a;
```

Passes. However,

```
type THasFoo = {foo: string};
const b: THasFoo = {foo: "hi", bar: "world"} as const;
```

Does not. It is the latter form of checking I would love to have (but without widening).

Comment: What would be the use case scenario?

Comment: I can only come up with something like this: `const b = (<T extends THasFoo>(v: T) => v)(a);`

Comment: @zerkms I do some type extraction over the constant (typeof a)["foo"], combined with conditional types I can actually do a lot with it.

Comment: Your approach of combining it with a lambda is what I've done so far, but it actually allows me to do things I don't want. I.e. `{foo: "hi", bar: "world"}` CANNOT be assigned to something of type THasFoo, but CAN be assigned to something using an extends lambda

Comment: "CANNOT be assigned" --- why? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gMxCAXDARACwEtcAaGAIzgCccAWAJgF94IZRIoBuGAeh5igBPAA4BTEGiSoM2PEVyMAUIqFiYAFQAScCADFMU9JhzQqhMAHNGnRe2gUcWnfpBS43PgJHjJyJ3swgA

Comment: You'll get a complaint from the compiler that THasFoo has no member bar

Comment: It happily passes type-check, see the link I just provided (sorry for the late edit)

Comment: Here it is with direct assignment :) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gMxCAXDARACwEtcAaGAIzgCccAWAJgF94IZRIoBuGAeh5igBPAA4BTEGiSoM2PEVyMAUIqFiYAFQAScCADFMU9JhzQqhMAHNGnRe2gUcWnfpCGZOAsTKUaMBtd5+VXFJZCc9TCA

Comment: Yep, that's by design: I think you need to make that point a bit more explicit in the question, I can see it now, but from reading the question first time I couldn't see that.

Comment: Actually, @zerkms, I take it back - the lambda approach does check this (Assuming you pass it directly and not as a variable). Thank you! If you post it as an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preamble: I don't hold black belt in TypeScript so my answer might be sub-optimal (or even worse)

```
const b = (<T extends THasFoo>(v: T) => v)(a);
```

So, it creates an anonymous function and immediately invokes it. If instead of `a` variable the literal is passed - it would follow the same assignability rules (like: literals must have exactly the same properties) as if it was a direct assignment.

Drawback: it makes one unnecessary function call, but probably modern engines could inline or entirely eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on how exactly you're trying to use this so maybe @zerkms answer is exactly what you are looking for, but my mind jumped to [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  We define a function that checks if any object has a `foo` property which is a `string`.  If the function returns `true`, then typescript narrows the type to include `THasFoo` without widening anything.

```
const hasFoo = <T extends {foo?: any}>(object: T): object is T & THasFoo => {
    return typeof object.foo === "string";
}

const a = {foo: "hi", bar: 42} as const;
if (hasFoo(a)) {
    console.log(a); // a gets refined to { readonly foo: "hi"; readonly bar: 42; } & THasFoo
}

const b = {foo: "hi", bar: 42};
if (hasFoo(b)) {
    console.log(b); // b gets refined to { foo: string; bar: number; } & THasFoo
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/4Wy22w)

Comment: I like this answer so much

Comment: I want a generic version of this. eg. `const myObject : isOfType<Foo> = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is as a result of excess properties. You can disable this checking with the [`suppressExcessPropertyErrors`  flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#suppressExcessPropertyErrors).

Playground: [suppressExcessPropertyErrors off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?suppressExcessPropertyErrors=false#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgCQIYGcBiB7DMC8MDeAZlgFwwogBOAlgHYDmAvgNzADGGtFMARmYqkzY8RUjABEAC2riANLySUy4gO4ZKAGwAm4xjFQwOXEKyA)

Playground: [suppressExcessPropertyErrors on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?suppressExcessPropertyErrors=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgCQIYGcBiB7DMC8MDeAZlgFwwogBOAlgHYDmAvgNzADGGtFMARmYqkzY8RUjABEAC2riANLySUy4gO4ZKAGwAm4xjFQwOXEKyA)